# fs.js:646 return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am new with angular 5 , Currently i have updated my project which was in angular 2 to 5 , but while i am running npm install command i am getting following error .

```
fs.js:646
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), 
mode);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/bijay/projects/project_name/config/Config.d.ts'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bijay/projects/project_name/node_modules/node-config-ts/src/createTypedefs.js:14:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

So I am not able to get what is the issue. And if i run npm install with Sudo it is working without any error.

Comment: I think you may have issue with file and directory naming conventions.
 Your dir may be have "_" or others symbol, you only can use characters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> var notesString = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');

no such file or directory, open

your directory place is empty or wrong

Answer (score 0):

For me it works when i run the code in the specific path using the terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35413699)

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar error. Downgrading from npm version 6.1.0 to 6.0.1 with the following command solved the error for me:

```
npm i npm@6.0.1 -g
```